# How to find the mean of non-zero values by group?

Tags: r, sum, data.table

I want to find the mean of non-zero values by group for multiple columns:

```
mydata<- data[, lapply(.SD, function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)), by=group, 
                        .SDcols=c("col1", "col2")]
```

What should I add to the above code?

Comment: When you say "add non-zero values" do you mean "count non-zero values"? Since x + 0 = x, adding non-zero values is the same as adding *all* values.

Comment: @Soheil `sum(c(-1, 0, 2))` and `sum(c(-1, 2)` are the same.  Only way there is a difference is when there is only 0 values for a group and then you may get `NA`

Comment: My bad, I wanted to calculate the mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We subset the elements that are not 0 (`x[x!=0]`) for each column specified in `.SDcols` and get the `mean` by 'group'

```
data[, lapply(.SD, function(x) mean(x[x!=0], na.rm=TRUE)), by =group,
                 .SDcols= c('col1', 'col2')]
```

Comment: I was trying only `x!=0` which obviously calculate something else. I keep the question since I was looking for a while, it might be useful.

Comment: @Soheil Your code `mean` and the `sum` in title is confusing along with no reproducible example/expected output.

Comment: @Soheil Your code should work if you just want the `sum` as `0` doesn't have any effect as Gregor mentioned in the comments